# Return XML content on WebAPI OWIN for Twilio

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm making a pretty simple WebAPI using OWIN/Katana self-hosted in a Azure Worker role. Everything is fine from the host perspective since I receive the request and it is routed to my Action just fine.

The problem is that the action MUST return a XML for the API caller/invoker and it is return a wrong encoding string as follow:

```
RAW Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 150
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 16 Jul 2014 05:49:42 GMT

<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;Response&gt;
  &lt;Say&gt;Hello World&lt;/Say&gt;
&lt;/Response&gt;</string>

RAW Request: 


GET http://localhost:81/v1/ivr/menu?from=+12345&to=645645&callsid=11111111 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:81
Content-Type: text/xml;

response.ToString() result:

<Response>
  <Say>Hello World</Say>
</Response>

API Controller Action code:

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("menu")]
        public IHttpActionResult Menu(string from, string to, string callSid) 
        {
            var response = new TwilioResponse();
            response.Say("Hello World");

            return Ok(response.ToString());
        }
```

Well, all I need is to return the XML as this:

```
    <Response>
      <Say>Hello World</Say>
    </Response>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? The response is coming between  tags and with a weird xmlns with what seems to be a wrong encoding...

I've tried to add Content-Type and Accept headers on the request to text/xml(I can't use application/xml but even if I do, it don't changes the output response)...

Also I've tried to create a OWINMiddleware that force the Response content type to text/xml as this:

```
public class XmlResponseMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public XmlResponseMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {

    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        await this.Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

No lucky...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("menu")]
public HttpResponeMessage Menu(string from, string to, string callSid) 
{
     var response = new TwilioResponse();
     response.Say("Hello World");

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            response.ToString(), 
            Encoding.UTF8, 
            "text/xml"
        )
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was already answered, but the answer required changing your response type from an IHttpActionResult to an HttpResponeMessage.
If you want to preserve the IHttpActionResult (and make it a little cleaner) you can do this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

[HttpGet]
[Route("menu")]
public IHttpActionResult Menu(string from, string to, string callSid) 
{
     var response = new TwilioResponse();
     response.Say("Hello World");

     return Ok(XElement.Parse(response.ToString()));
}
```

In your WebApiConfig, add this to the register.
It will cause XML to be the default.
Why Twilio doesn't include application/xml as an accept header is beyond me.

```
  config.Formatters.Clear();
  config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
  config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
  config.Formatters.Add(new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
```